# Camera roll trying to send email from inactive account

Tags: iphone, email, camera

I have an iPhone which had an exchange account as the default for mail. That account was inactivated on the Exchange side. Without realizing that, I tried sharing photos by email.

They now seem to be stuck in a queue, trying repeatedly to send, because I get pop ups asking for my exchange login info. Even after having set a gmail account as the default for sending mail.

I'm afraid these attempts to send using the exchange account are draining my battery. How can I stop the camera app from trying to send these photos? Would deleting the exchange account on the phone do it? Anything else I should try first?

Answer (score 1):

Your new Gmail default should apply for any new messages. But to delete messages that are already sending, you need to open the Mail app, choose the Exchange account (not the inbox), then look in the outbox folder and delete the messages from there.

Comment: I would delete that account from the phone, temporarily, or at least be sure and make it Inactive in settings.